# Code First Transaction wrapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions

We have an existing database with a user table and a code base (written in VB.Net) that implements certain business logic and handles adding "legacy user" records to the database. A project I am working on now requires the creation of a new entity (ExternalUser) which "extends" user. We chose to implement the new entity by creating a legacy user record and linking it in a one to one relationship with a new table. When asked to create a new ExternalUser the UserRepository would then call on the legacy code to create the User part of the record and then the repository would use EF Code first ExternalUserContext to create the record in the ExternalUsers table.
Of course if the second call should fail for any reason, we would like to have the creation of the legacy user reversed. This is where things are failing. We are using SQL Server 2005 and EF Code 4.3.1. Here is the relevant code:

```
using (_context = new ExternalUserContext(Utils.ConnectionString))
{
     ObjectContext ob = ((IObjectContextAdapter) _context).ObjectContext;
     ob.Connection.Open();
     DbTransaction tran = ob.Connection.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
     _legacyUser = new blUser();
     long id = _legacyUser.Add(//Params go here);
     if (id > 0)
     {
         toCreate.UserID = id;
         _context.ExternalUsers.Add(toCreate);
         tran.Rollback(); //Just for testing
         throw new FieldAccessException("testing"); //just for testing
         _context.SaveChanges();
         tran.Commit();
      }else
      {
          throw new ArgumentException("Could not create legacy user");
      }
 }
```

I have tried using the TransactionScope (started either before or after instantiating the ExternalUserContext) before trying to explicitly manage the transaction all to no avail. The quoted code would throw the error but the user record remains in the database. The VB code is calling another .dll that does the actual record creation. Both dlls wrap the creation in a TransactionScope with default settings.

Is the fact that my code is calling a dll that in itself is calling a dll that performs the database transaction playing a role here? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry to say that it turns out that this was due to a bad case of code fragmentation.  The source code I have for the low level dll that does the insert is not the one used to generate the binary my project refrences.  Among the differences is the fact that the transactionscope is defined as RequiresNew.  Sorry to have wasted anyones time..... it can still be used as an example of how bad version control can waste a days work!!